# What is the correct plural of "training"?

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english

English isn't my mother tongue, and when we recently talked to a native speaker (during some company audit), he pointed out that the plural word "trainings" is actually wrong (he pointed that it is a very common mistake and was almost amused by it).

I couldn't understand why and wondered what the correct plural of "training" would be. Online Dictionaries/Thesaurus don't answer it, so it's probably another opinion-based statement. I haven't found a source to back it up, though.

Comment: It might be safer to just say 'training courses'.

Comment: Whether it is correct or not, I doubt that I am the only corporate-employee being frequently asked to verify that I have completed and kept current on all of my required training**s** (in other words, web-based brain-washes to ensure I don't harass my co-workers or leak company secrets on facebook.)

Comment: For me an s on training (because I am a translator from languages that do have a plural for it) is an immediate red flag. training courses, I'm will Miles. /Our company held ten training courses or sessions this year/. So, maybe in some geek (computing forums), it may be acceptable, it is not acceptable in  most places where training is actually done or provided...It is not acceptable in formal register texts.

Comment: Do not say; "The school gave me trainings in physics and chemistry."  For that, use "training".  If you were using "trainings" in this way, that would be why the native speaker said it was incorrect.

Comment: By pointing out that it is a "very common mistake", isn't he basically proving his own case wrong?  Languages change over time, and if a word takes on a new meaning to a large population, it doesn't really matter to those people what dictionaries say that word means.  In fact, often dictionaries will soon *include* the new definition.

Comment: How was the word "trainings" used? It's hard to judge whether a usage is correct or incorrect if we can't see the actual usage. Informal English permits you to make an uncountable noun plural when there's an omitted countable noun implied after it. For example, "I've read books about ancient London and modern London. Of these two Londons, I prefer ..." You can do the same with "trainings" as short for "training types".

Comment: A [2006 movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borat) used the pluralization of a gerund _in the subtitle_ to mock its main character's poor grasp of English.  "Training" is almost always used in an uncountable sense ("He needs more training in the language"); if you have a plural sense, use the word as an adjective modification a countable noun, like "course", "day", or "experience".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Training* is both countable and uncountable. Usually, referring to a process, it is uncountable and has no plural.

It is sometimes used to mean "a specific training event", and is then countable, and has the plural "trainings". The OED has examples of this use going back to 1578, with the plural recorded from 1598.

Comment: Actually the plural version has been more commonly used in recent years: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trainings&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrainings%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JOSH It might be more instructive to compare the usage of [both forms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=training%2Ctrainings&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctraining%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrainings%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Mick - no, I am not saying that the plural form is more common than the singular one, but just that its usage has increased. And from your graph you can't see that.

Comment: @Mick - Also the word "training" will include uses as a verb (e.g. "he is training me") rather than just as a noun (whether countable or uncountable).

Comment: Context is everything and resistance [to that] is futile. "Our company provides on-site trainings to widget manufacturers":nix that. "Our company provides on-site training courses or sessions to widget manufacturers". Disembodied (uncontextualized) arguments about single words such as this word is silly.

Comment: I hear what you say and have looked at the OED examples to which you refer. But I wouldn't put *trainings* into my personal style guide.

Answer (score 23):

*Training* is normally used as an [*uncountable noun*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns) by native English speakers, and in this form it doesn't take a plural. However, some dictionaries list it as being both countable and uncountable, with the caveat that the countable form is little used. Google Ngrams shows the relative frequencies for both forms:

[image]

Interestingly, Google Ngrams indicates that usage of *trainings* is on the increase. Unfortunately, we have no way of knowing how much this is influenced by native English speakers adopting the countable form.

[image]

The Cambridge Dictionary and Collins Dictionary indicate that it is uncountable. The Oxford Living Dictionaries indicates that it is a mass noun. Wiktionary mentions the plural form, but says that it is not often used. Other online dictionaries offer no opinion. No online dictionary that I can find provides an example of usage as a countable noun.

I don't think that I have heard a fellow native English speaker use the countable form. If I have, it would be only rarely. My own feeling is that you should avoid using the countable form if you ever have ambitions of being mistaken for a native English speaker.

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=training%2Ctrainings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctraining%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrainings%3B%2Cc0)

[Cambridge Dictionary: Training](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/training)

[Collins Dictionary: Training](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/training)

[Oxford Living Dictionaries: Training](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/training)

[Wiktionary: Training](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/training)

Comment: This is only half the answer.

Comment: @ColinFine It's the half that I'm happy with.

Comment: If you don't choose to use the countable "training", fine. But answering as if it doesn't exist is doing a disservice to the questioner.

Comment: @Colin I will amend my answer. It would be interesting if you could provide in your answer some modern examples of native English writers using the countable form.

Comment: A  comment from Quora : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-plural-of-training

Comment: A usage example from U.N. Papers (2006) "***Specialized trainings*** for trainers end with a test. A certificate bearing participant's name is issued afterwards. Obligated institutions ***sent to such trainings***  those employees"... https://books.google.it/books?id=lwStCTTPIq4C&pg=PA11&dq=%22trainings%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWxrCh_uvPAhXnJsAKHbvgAXs4ChDoAQg2MAM#v=onepage&q=%22trainings%22&f=false

Comment: @AndyT "Noun [U]" (thanks for the help)

Comment: @JOSH Interesting, but *trainings* seems to mean *training sessions* in this instance. Also, there is no guarantee that the document was prepared by a native English speaker.

Comment: Yes, as Colin Fine says in his answers, "a specific training event". There are more examples available if you want. I don't think it is a native vs non native issue.

Comment: GloWbE shows 372 instances of "trainings" from US sources, 176 from GB, 101 from Canada, 88 from Australia. Interestingly, it shows 170 from India, 201 from the Philippines, 317 from Kenya and 462 from Tanzania. So the word is apparently considerably more common in Asian and African Englishes than British, But it is clearly in use. And I am a native English speaker, and use it.

Comment: For comparison, the figures for "training" as a noun are tw orders of magnitude larger, and not in the same proportions. eg US 37842, GB 55632, TZ 11538.

Comment: @Colin I am wondering how much the increase in usage of the uncountable form was driven by the industrial revolution. It seems clearly to be a 19th and early 20th century event.

Comment: @Mick : _"No online dictionary that I can find ..."_ The wikipedia page you refer to actually has a hyperlink to the ["plural form"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trainings#English) with 3 quotes. However, a handful of quotes is not "proof" as they themselves could be mistakes. (It's a line of logic that leads to "teh" being an alternate spelling for "the".) It would be more useful to compare uses of training in ***plural context*** as uncountable noun vs. countable. I don't know how to do this, but did compare: "training sessions" vs "trainings". The results are interesting...

Comment: @Andy, Oxford's dictionary is considered "Learner's" not due to simplified examples but limiting the word usage in the descriptions to just 3000 most basic ones. So while targeted for learners it never narrows answers to only simple cases.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is unbiased towards any of the options. While Colin Fine's answer is an interesting fact it does not mean nowadays we should (or shouldn't) use "training" as a countable noun. I also wonder to what level does the increase of non-native speakers contribute to the suddenly raising usage of the pluralised form.

Answer (score 9):

Using the plural of gerunds (that is a present participle used as a noun, and then pluralized) is only recently more common.

Gerunds are non-count nouns, but describe a process not the thing that is processing. There is a perceptible lexical gap of a noun for those things and to fill it there is semantic shift of X-ing to an individual object X-ed)

> I was learning today (present participle)
>
> Learning took place today (gerund)
>
> What were your *learnings* today? (countable object)

As to usage, a newspaper editor or school teacher will mark this as terribly wrong because it sounds very grating on first hearing, like a foreignism. However it is becoming more common in business-speak. I would recommend not using it, but now you know how to recognize it when used:

> 'X-ings' = 'things X-ed'

Which is all to say that 'trainings' is the correct plural, but you probably want to avoid it and use 'training sessions' or 'skills we were trained for' depending on purpose.

Comment: While many gerunds are uncountable, there are lots of gerunds which are used as count nouns: *findings, pickings, teachings, fixings, tidings, savings*. And some of these have been around for centuries: [savings](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=savings) since 1737, and Shakespeare used *blessings, greetings* and *proceedings*.

Comment: @PeterShor hmm... yes. overgeneralization on my part. Anyway, that means the excrescent (to me) sounding 'learnings' and 'trainings' are in good company with many perfectly acceptable sounding words.

Comment: Which is exactly why people learning English have trouble with this.

Comment: @PeterShor Many of your examples appear to be mass nouns that normally take a plural form, like *mathematics* and *cards*. When could you pluralize *fixing* to get *fixings* or *saving* to get *savings*? *A proceeding* and *the proceedings* refer to two entirely different things, one legal, and the other administratative. The issue seems to be whether or not words such as *trainings* behave as group nouns. To me, they don't. In the few cases where I can concoct a plural fitting your list, I always end up adding some other noun such as sets, events, actions, etc.

Comment: @Phil: That may be true, but it's really not of any help explaining why *trainings* is unacceptable and *teachings* is a valid word, which was the OP's question.

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe because *the teaching of Buddhism* and *the teachings of Buddhism* are two different things? I can't think of a rule or class of words that *trainings* fits. Would we say *the trainings of Bela Karolyi*?

Comment: @PeterShor Interestingly, [*physic*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=physic) (c. 1300) is the older form of [*physics*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=physics) (1580s). No one bats an eyelid at the new-fangled form now. (Not a gerund, I know).

Answer (score 7):

Although some treat *training* as an uncountable noun (that is, never used in the plural), the plural form *trainings* is [in widespread use](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22trainings%22).

If you want to follow prescriptivism, you can use *training sessions*.

Comment: I didn't think I was a prescriptivist, but whereas I'm fine with *Three teachings of a great philosopher,* I'm certainly not keen on *Three trainings of [with?] a great instructor*. And although it doesn't necessarily count for *much*, even the Google Chrome spellchecker objects to my writing the plural in that last sentence.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't consider a word used in about 400 known books in the English language to be "widespread use". I would consider that clearly to be a very narrow spread of use readily explained by mostly people writing in their non-native language plus perhaps a few typos.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mick that training is an uncountable noun. In the example given by Mr. Fine of a specific training event allowing training to become countable, I disagree. In the case of becoming countable, the portion being counted is the event. Therefor, it would be "there are multiple training events available at the pavilion" (or whatever).
I see many cases where much effort is made to "fix" the plural when a simple rewording will eliminate the contentious context and allow an, arguably, better flow by using the standard form.

Comment: You disagree with what? With the fact that some people use the word in that way? If so, you are wrong. As I said to Mick, you are welcome to eschew the use, and even to advise against its use. But, to take your own words, "I see many cases where much effort is made" to avoid a perfectly clear and useful word and insist on an unnecessary circumlocution.

Comment: That is a harsh response, my view. I'm sure you will disagree. My disagreement stands clearly. I disagree that the scenario you offered allows training to be pluralized by adding an "s". Creating words to allow curious plurals to be applied is not good writing, my view.

Comment: What do you mean by “allows”? There is no governing body over the English language, and no one to dictate what is allowed and what is illegal. There is only established/conventional and unestablished/unconventional usages—plus of course the very large field that falls in between, being not quite common enough to be conventional, but not rare or nonce enough to be unconventional, either. _Trainings_ is used by competent native speakers of English, is clear and unambiguous, and is in the process of being conventionalised. Creating unwieldy constructions to avoid simpler ones is not good writing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet but 'trainings'? It just sounds so wrong, like throwing with your non-dominant hand, it's possible and may be more practical in certain situations, but it feels all sorts of wrong.

Comment: @Mitch I'm with Colin here: I don’t find it wrong or even jarring at all. It’s a bit jargony and mostly something you’d expect to find in business speak, but it’s fairly natural and unwrong to my ear. I wouldn’t notice or balk at it if I saw it in writing (provided it was used in a way that makes sense). To me, it’s already quite conventionalised; to others, not at all. That’s what I meant by it being in the process of being conventionalised.

Comment: @Janus I have a sneaking suspicion that Colin uses it to have a little bit of fun with more traditional users of the English language.

Comment: @ColinFine Dumb question - what aspect of the situation triggers the plural? If one person gets one instance of training in X - singular. Presumably, if one group of people get one instance of training in X - singular. If two groups get training in X - which is it? If one group gets training in X and Y - which is it? If two groups get training in X and Y respectively - which is it? If two groups get training in both X and Y - which is it? If an unspecified number of groups get training in an unspecified number of things - which is it?

Comment: For a bean-counting business administrator, it is obvious that two learnings are twice as valuable as one learning, so it logically follows that two trainings must be twice as valuable as one training. But the above sentence isn't *English*, IMHO.

Comment: In conversational speech, *trainings* can be considered a shortening of *training sessions* or *training exercises* and that seems ok. But it definitely sounds weird in a formal context.

Comment: I have nearly thirty years experience in an organisation which offers weekend (and other workshops) which are referred to as trainings. It may be that in 1988 I found this a strange or jargony usage (though I don't remember doing so) but now it is a normal part of my vocabulary.